# How to add a break after Symfony's formType labels

Tags: html, forms, symfony, generated

I have some issues to put a break after my input's labels generated by my Symfony's Form.
Here is the form :
[my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ozVk.png)
Here is my twig :
[my twig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WJaC.png)
And this is what I have now, I just want to return on the line after each label so my quizz finally looks like a quizz ;) :
[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnTaM.jpg)

If you know the way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [form_theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#create-your-own-form-theme) and make a custom one.

Did you try calling `form_row(form.choix)` instead of `form_widget(form.choix)` ?

Comment: So I take a look at the documentation about form theme but to be honest I didn't see how to do what I want :/ The fact that my row form.choix concern all my choices make the thing a little more complicated for me. When I call form_row, I have all the options of choix. I tried this in my form but it only shows me the label of my choice and the "<br>"  :                     'choice_label'=> function($choix)
                    {
                        return $choix->getLabelChoix()."<br>";
                    },